# Variable inlet velocity implementation in ANSYS Fluent

Tags: fluid-mechanics, ansys, fluent

I'm trying to perform 2D analysis for a steady laminar incompressible flow through a horizontal channel with a height of H (m) and length of 2H. The boundary conditions is of the form:

$u=\frac{3}{2}U_{avg}\left(1-\frac{2y}{H}\right),v=0$ at $x=0$,

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0,\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=0$ at $x=2H$,

with no-slip condition at the walls. Is it possible to implement these boundary conditions in Fluent? I think that UDF may help but I have no experience dealing with it. Thanks in advance, I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you have already found a way or not, but for others just posting the answer. You can always refer the Fluent UDF user guide and samples.
These are few additional examples which you can refer:

https://www.learncax.com/knowledge-base/blog/by-category/cfd/writing-a-user-defined-function-udf-in-ansys-fluent

[https://www.southampton.ac.uk/~zxie/SESS6021/udf_tut1.pdf](https://www.southampton.ac.uk/%7Ezxie/SESS6021/udf_tut1.pdf)

Thanks